# How to select a text block when soft keyboard shows up

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, selection

I am displaying an alert box with edit text for user to change the name of a file.

However, I want to auto select the name of the file expect for the suffix (for example: ".jpg").

I use `EditText.setSelection(0, name.length()-4)` and the name block is selected as I wished.

But, when I click on the edit text to bring on the soft keyboard, the selection is gone.

How to keep the selection from disappearing? Or, how can I automatically set the selection when the soft keyboard is displayed?

Following is my code of showing the alert dialog:

```
private void updateItemFileName(final long ID, final String oldName) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter new name");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        input.setText(oldName);
        /* Select the "name" block except for the suffix*/
        input.setSelection(0, oldName.length() - 4);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //TODO: change the name and refresh list view
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.create().show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting focus and specifically instructing Android to provide the keyboard? Try this on for size:

```
if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```

This should give the focus to the EditText and open up the keyboard while your selection is still selected. From your question, I'm interpreting that while the filename is selected, the EditText is not focused and touching the EditText then unselects the filename.

Comment: I am using alert dialog. Where should I put this code? You can refer to my code I have added to the question.

Comment: Have you tried putting it before you call `builder.setView(input)`? Remember to change `myEditText` in my example code to `input`, as that's what you called your EditText.